# where does the emit method in python log handler return to?

Tags: python, logging

In the python log handler class

there should be a emit method.

when I write a return statement

Where does it return to?

Answer (score 1):

`emit()` is usually called by the loggers `handle()` method, but the return value is not used.

See here: [logging module source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L963)